# Read command throws bad variable name error in script, but not from terminal

Tags: curl, scripting, openwrt, ash

I'm trying to curl the script:

```
#!/bin/ash
echo "Text Prompt: "
read REPLY
echo $REPLY
```

However, I get this output:

```
Text Prompt:
: bad variable name
```

When I run the command from the terminal, it works fine. I've also tried the following with similar results:

```
#!/bin/ash
read -p "Text Prompt: " vName=$REPLY
echo vName

#!/bin/ash
read -p "Text Prompt: " && vName=$REPLY
echo vName
```

Comment: you meant `echo "$vName"` (leading `$`) didn't you? Also `REPLY` is the default variable for `read` but you can specify and use any varName you care to, so `read -p "Text Prompt: " vName` should work. (in `bash` anyway). Test your code with `bash` and see if that makes a difference. I would expect your 1st example to work in `bash`. . The `curl` tag seems unneeded. Good luck.

Comment: Tried using `bash` and the method you recommended, with no luck still. Eventually, the device that this will be running on only has the `ash` shell, and no way to run the script locally, hence why I'm testing using `curl`

Comment: you should update your Q with fixed syntax. We can't help you if you stick with `echo vName` (it needs the leading `$`! ;-) . Are you getting these results when "sending in the command to run" via `curl`? Or are you saying that the code above doesn't work in a `terminal` running on the remote hardware (with the `ash` shell) ?. They are really 2 separate problems, so readers will need to be able to copy/paste code into a specific environment to get the errors you are getting. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing in notepad++, which adds windows-specific newline characters onto the end of the line. Tried doing it in sublime and it worked immediately.